# How can I find the minimum value of an array in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, minimum

I have a excel VBA macro which is to be used to calculate the size of a machined part.  The first part of the macro is set up to obtain values from a worksheet and calculates an area based on some predefined options and prints them to excel.  The second part is where I have some issues.

I have converted the table to a 2D array (save processing time) and started to fill in the array via 2 loops, 1 controls the row, 1 the column.  Within the loop I am trying to find the minimum none zero value and the associated column, this then helps with the final part of the macro which works.  I have also set the min number to be a large value which will never be exceeded.

When I run the macro step by step the first none zero value I come across resets the min value to zero and does not change the column number.  Can anyone guide me as to where I have gone wrong?

```
maxtubesel = Sheets("Tube OD").Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row - 4

'Find min and col value in array
Dim resarray() As Long
ReDim resarray(maxtubesel, 5)
min = 1000000
col = 0
For m = 0 To 2 ' maxtubesel
    For n = 0 To 4
        resarray(m, n) = Sheets("Tube OD").Cells(4 + m, 26 + n)
            If Sheets("Tube OD").Cells(4 + m, 26 + n) <> "" Or Sheets("Tube OD").Cells(4 + m, 26 + n) <> 0 Then
                min = Sheets("Tube OD").Cells(4 + m, 26 + n) And col = n
            End If
    Next n
Next m
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
min = Sheets("Tube OD").Cells(4 + m, 26 + n) And col = n
```

should be two lines

```
min = Sheets("Tube OD").Cells(4 + m, 26 + n)
col = n
```

otherwise what actually happens is you set `min` to a boolean value that checks if these two statements are both true:

```
Sheets("Tube OD").Cells(4 + m, 26 + n)
col = n
```

It seems they're not, so `min = False` and that's a value of zero :)